# Is the original photo in an iPhoto library still saved if I trash the photo after dragging it to the desktop?

Tags: macos, photos.app, photos, graphics

If I move a photo from iPhoto to the desktop, and then trash, is the original still saved in the library?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes.

You can't move a photo from iPhoto out of the library simply by dragging it. It'll be a copy, therefore deleting it from the desktop will not remove the original from the iPhoto library.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved it, no.
If you copied it, yes.

It really depends *how* you 'moved' it.

Comment: I selected a number of photos (Shift click) and dragged them to the desktop. Then dragged them to the trash

Comment: dragged from where? iTunes itself, or the Finder?